# Mail the content of a txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file result.txt on my desktop. I want a windows batch script which can mail the content of result.txt to a set of recipients.

Comment: you'll need external utility like blat..Or vbscript/jscript and cdo object or powershell

Comment: thanks a lot ...!! blat seems to be a perfect command line utility to send mails .

Comment: Ok.Will put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need external utility like [blat](http://www.blat.net/)..Or [vbscript/jscript](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm) and cdo object or [powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2012/03/16/sending-email-using-powershell-script.aspx)